# getting "SVN\db\txn-protorevs\7500-5vd.rev: There is not enough space on disk" error while commit

Tags: svn

I am getting the "SVN\db\txn-protorevs\7500-5vd.rev: There is not enough space on disk" error while doing commit on the totosise svn.

Comment: Even if i would have never heard anything about svn i would check free space on my disk ....

Comment: I got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The server where SVN holds the repository is out of disk space. If you have access to it, log-on and see whether there is any tidying-up you can do (temp files, etc). If it's not under your control, you'll have to speak to who-ever the server admin is to get the disk cleaned-up, and maybe additional space allocated to the volume where the SVN repo lives.

Comment: What if the server where SVN holds the repository has 40g free?  I'm experiencing this specific problem.